# How do I remove favicon link from source of the web page?

Tags: html, css, web

[This is a webpage image of the favicon.ico i want to to remove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWZLG.jpg)

I have deleted the image and the link ( )from the source and the icon keep showing. I even tried replacing it another icon but still getting the same result.

Comment: Your browser is probably caching it.

Comment: Thank you. You were right. I clear the cache and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Favicons are cached, if you'd like to replace it, I'd suggest to add a version i.e. `favicon.ico?v=RyyR6aw6zk` this will force the browser to load the new icon

Answer (score 0):

I work out it when I prevent request to the favicon.

Answer (score 0):

you can filter the request to the favicon so that you can give your own favicon .